# A simple quadratic reformulation of the twin prime conjecture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, twin-primes

Due to https://oeis.org/A024702 we have that $p^2 - 1 ≡ 0$ (mod 24).

For twin primes, we then must also have that in this case $(p+2)^2 - 1 ≡ 0$ (mod 24), which is the same as saying that $p^2 + 4p + 3 ≡ 0$ (mod 24).

Adding these and dividing both sides by 2, one would then have a simple quadratic reformulation of the twin primes conjecture like so:

**There are infinitely many primes *p* such that $p^2 + 2p + 1 ≡ 0$ (mod 12).**

Is that correct? Would it possibly be of any practical benefit, like extending it to prime gaps of arbitrary size that have been proven already, and then "proving backwards" towards a gap of size 2?

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that all numbers of the form $n=6k\pm 1$, not just primes, satisfy the relationship $n^2-1 \equiv 0 \bmod 24$. Such pairs of numbers may contain $0,1,\text{ or }2$ primes, e.g. $(119,121),(23,25),(47,49),(11,13)$. So even if there are infinitely many numbers such that $n^2+2n+1\equiv 0 \bmod 12$, this is not equivalent to the assertion that there are infinitely many prime numbers with that property.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not equivalent to the twin prime conjecture.  Any $p$ such that $p \equiv 5$ or $11 \mod 12$ satisfies $p^2+2p+1 \equiv 0 \mod 12$.  But most of them are not twin primes.  Counterexamples are easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

No use , a **slightly** better reformulation is: There exists infinitely many semiprimes of form $p^2+2p$ , where $p$ is prime. It's still basically useless though...